# Как получить данные из другого DataFrame по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, join

У меня есть 2 фрейма: `SpendDF` и `MainDF`, у которых два общих поля: `ad_id` и `Date`.
В фрейме `SpendDF` есть поле `spend`, которое нужно сопоставить всем строчкам из `MainDF`, у которых происходит совпадение этих двух общих полeй. В фрейме `MainDF` может быть несколько строчек с одинаковыми `ad_id` и `Date` и у них должны быть одинаковые значения `spend`.

```
SpendDF
               Date  campaign     ad_id  spend
    0  11-02-19  11484480  32631604  49.18
    1  11-02-19  11484485  32631612  33.19
    2  11-02-19  11484611  32631778   2.52
    3  11-02-19  11487692  32636729   7.08
    4  11-02-19  11487692  32636730   7.47
MainDF
             Date Campaign    id     ad_id   os  Installs   app
    0  2019-03-01      MSK  1190  36296008  ios       0.0  real
    1  2019-03-01      MSK  1190  36296013  serv       0.0  real
    2  2019-03-01      MSK  1190  36296013  ios       0.0  real
    3  2019-03-01      MSK  1190  36296022  ios       0.0  real
    4  2019-03-01      MSK  1190  36296023  ios       0.0  real
```

Там достаточно болшие фреймы, они не отсортированы, но все `ad_id` и `Date` из первого присутствуют во втором в нескольких вариантах (тут видно `serv` и следующий за ним `ios`).

Я использую:

```
ResultDF = MainDF.merge(SpendDF[['ad_id','Date','spend']],on=['ad_id','Date'],how='inner')
```

Но в итоге получаю пустой фрейм. А если использую:

```
ResultDF = MainDF.merge(SpendDF[['ad_id','Date','spend']],on='ad_id',how='inner')
```

, то получаю:

```
        Date_x Campaign     ad_id   os  Installs   app    Date_y  spend
0   2019-03-01      MSK  36374447  ios       0.0  real  11-02-19   1.14
1   2019-03-01      MSK  36374447  ios       0.0  real  12-02-19   1.94
2   2019-03-01      MSK  36374447  ios       0.0  real  13-02-19   2.09
3   2019-03-01      MSK  36374447  ios       0.0  real  14-02-19   1.60
4   2019-03-01      MSK  36374447  ios       0.0  real  15-02-19   1.29
5   2019-03-01      MSK  36374447  ios       0.0  real  16-02-19   3.22
6   2019-03-01      MSK  36374447  ios       0.0  real  17-02-19   4.26
7   2019-03-01      MSK  36374453  ios       0.0  real  11-02-19   3.79
8   2019-03-01      MSK  36374453  ios       0.0  real  12-02-19   2.49
9   2019-03-01      MSK  36374453  ios       0.0  real  13-02-19   4.21
10  2019-03-01      MSK  36374453  ios       0.0  real  14-02-19   6.26
11  2019-03-01      MSK  36374453  ios       0.0  real  15-02-19   7.38
12  2019-03-01      MSK  36374453  ios       0.0  real  16-02-19   9.87
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас не совпадают типы данных в столбце "Date" - в одном DF тип столбца `object`, а в другом - `datetime`. Убедитесь что в обоих фреймах у столбцов, по которым идет объединение одинаковые типы данных.

Чтобы проверить тип данных всех столбцов DF:

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

Чтобы преобразовать строковые значения в `datetime:`

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors="coerce")
```

Comment: Преобразовал в обоих DF, но теперь при слиянии он теряет часть дат. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: попробуйте использовать merge(..., how=“left”) - это поможет найти отсутствующие  строки

Comment: Это помогло! Похоже дело было в том, что форматы даты были разные. У одного: YYYY-DD-MM, а у другого: YYYY-MM-DD